# Não redireciona no Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

O código a seguir não está funcionando no Firefox.

```
 <script>
         function go(){
           document.write('<p align="center">AGUARDE O ENCERRAMENTO...</p>');
         } 
         setInterval("go();", 3000);
         setInterval(function () { location.href = 'sair.php'; }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Bem-vinda o stackoverlow em português. Por favor, dê uma olhada na nossa [central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Mesmo eu que não percebo nada de javascript entendo o que se está perguntando. Em vez de votar para fechar não seria melhor tentar, primeiro, melhorá-la editando-a ou pedir esclarecimento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu código parece ter alguns erros, ou, melhor dizendo, não seria a melhor forma de se fazer.

`setInterval` gerará uma repetição em determinado intervalo. Se quer retardar o redirecionamento, use `setTimeout`, que conta um tempo e depois executa a função ao término desse tempo, porém uma só vez.

```
function go()
{
   document.write('<p align="center">AGUARDE O ENCERRAMENTO...</p>');
   setTimeout(function () { 
     location.href = '/sair.php'; 
   }, 5000);
} 


go();
```

Answer (score -3):

Quando usas setInterval ou setTimeout, o modo de executar uma função é diferente,
as aspas na chamada dela não existem, bem como os parênteses.

Assim:

```
function go(){
    document.write('AGUARDE O ENCERRAMENTO...');
}

setInterval(go, 3000);
setInterval(function(){
    location.href = 'sair.php'; 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Para que o setInterval? se vai ser redirecionado, para que usar uma função que gera uma repetição, se algo será executado apenas uma vez? E a sua afirmação está errada. Ela pode fazer a chamada da função em `setInterval` como string.

Comment: Apenas usei o exemplo baseado no código original, só ajustei o que era a dúvida dela mesmo.

Comment: Não resolveu o problema, você só alterou a sintaxe do código, mas ele faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: É claro que ela pode, não significa que ela deva ou que a string que tu comentou está correta (pois não se usa align=center há anos). A abordagem dela é ruim, eu só corrigi o não funcionamento do código baseado no conhecimento dela.

Comment: Não entendi nada.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters consegui resolver o que eu precisava, o código que passei funciona no IE e Chrome menos no FF então o que vc passou funcionou tbm no FF o do Jardel parece não funcionar por isso fiz a marcação.